# C# WinForms - Forms not talking to each other

Tags: c#, list, winforms, static, instance

I have three Forms *Main*, *Trend1* and *Selector*. A button from *Main* opens *Trend1*, that is in another project called *TRENDER*

```
    private void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Trend1 = new TRENDER.Trend1();
        Trend1.Show();            
    }
```

A MenuItem at *Trend1* is supposed to open an intance of *Selector* that is also in *TRENDER* project.

```
   private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Selector select = new Selector();
        select.ShowDialog();
    }
```

I want to have a multiple instances of *Trend1* and *Selector* opened at the same time. Each *Trend1* and *Selector* need to work as a couple, moving focus from each other and share some data. They need to share a List of Objects *RecItems* that is created at *Selector*. My problem is that *Trend1* **can see** the list only if I make is Static as:

```
public static List<RecItem> trend = new List<RecItem>();
```

If I make it without Static:

```
public List<RecItem> trend = new List<RecItem>();
```

Than I can work with it only at *Selector* as *Trend1* don't see at at all.

Static don't work for me as I need to have the subject list to be specific to each par of *Trend1* and *Selector* being opened at the same time.

What I'm doing wrong here and how to do it right?

Add:

I'm reading the list when *Trend1* gets reactivated.

```
        private void Trend1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Selector.FromSelector) {
            Selector.FromSelector = false;
            dataGridView1.RowCount = Selector.RecCount ; i = 0;
            foreach (RecItem Item in Selector.trend) {
                dataGridView1[0,i].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Item.R, 
                Item.G, Item.B);
                dataGridView1[1,i].Value = Item.Name;
                dataGridView1[2,i].Value = Item.Value;
                dataGridView1[3,i].Value = Item.EngUnit;
                dataGridView1[4,i].Value = Item.Max;
                dataGridView1[5,i].Value = Item.Min;
                dataGridView1[6,i].Value = Item.WIdth; 
                dataGridView1[7,i].Value = Item.Dots;
                i++;
            }
        }
```

It works OK with static there.

Comment: When/where are you reading this List? There's no code here that tries to access that **Field**. After `select.ShowDialog()` returns? Before and after that? (Btw, you can also see it in the Keywords colors used here: `select` is a bad name, change it to something else). -- Make a Public Property of Method in `Selector` (change that name, too), so the class can have some control over whatever other code tries to access a collection it owns. -- How the two classes are supposed to *move focus from each other* when one Form is shown as a modal dialog?

Comment: |I got it... It was all mass...all OK now... thanks